# Shebang support in reasonML

Tags: shebang, reason, bucklescript

I'm trying to write a command line tool in reasonML. So I inserted a shebang(`#! /usr/bin/env node`) at the first line, but the compiler failed to compile it. How do I add a shebang to the compiled output?

Comment: Could you compile to native code instead of JS? If it's a CLI, there are nice OCaml libraries which you can trivially reuse in Reason, e.g. https://github.com/janestreet/shexp

Answer (score 6):

I know of two ways to accomplish this:

**1. Use the `js-post-build` configuration option in `bsconfig.json`:**

Here's an example that uses `sed` to insert the shebang at the top of the generated js file:

```json
"js-post-build": {
  "cmd": "/usr/bin/sed -i '1 i\\#!/usr/bin/env node'"
}
```

[Documentation](https://bucklescript.github.io/docs/en/build-configuration.html#js-post-build)

This will execute on just the files that actually. The downside to this is that shebang is not valid javascript, so if you need to parse it later, for example to bundle, it might fail (like rollup, for example). BSB will also behave a bit glitchy, but I had no serious issues with this, just a bit of console spam from the build triggering a few hundred times more than it should.

**2. Use `rollup`s banner option:**

Webpack and other bundlers might have a similar feature, but I only know how to do this with rollup. Here's an example `rollup.config.js` configuration:

```js
export default {
  input: `src/main.bs.js`,
  output: {
    file: `bin/main.js`,
    format: 'cjs',
    banner: '#!/usr/bin/env node'
  }
}
```

[Documentation](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en#advanced-functionality)

The downside to this is of course that you have to use rollup, or some other tool that adds a build step you might not otherwise need.